# Changing CSS font color for ul item

Tags: html, css

I have a menu like so:

```
<ul class="ipro_menu">

    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active-parent"><a href="/menu-item-1/">Menu Item 1</a> 

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="/subitem-1/">Subitem 1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="/subitem-2/">Subitem 2</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="/menu-item-2/">Menu Item 2</a></li>

</ul>
```

The current page automatically gets the class `active` and if it is in a ul under the main ul (submenu), then the main ul element will get the class `active-parent`.

So, in the above example, we would be viewing the "Subitem 2" page, so "Menu Item 1" is given the class `active-parent`.

I am trying to change the font color of the `active-parent` ONLY- not all the submenu elements. Here's what I have:

```
ul.ipro_menu li.active-parent a {
color: #FF0000;
}
```

The problem is that this is changing not only the `active-parent` element, but all of the li's in the sub-menu as well.

How do I change this to only change the font color of the specific element marked `active-parent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That behavior is expected with CSS. The only way to override that style for children would be to use a separate (and more specific) style for those elements:

```
ul.ipro_menu li.active-parent ul.sub-menu li a {
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the active-parent class on the HREF:

http://jsfiddle.net/RAkuc/

```
<ul class="ipro_menu">

<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="active-parent" href="/menu-item-1/">Menu Item 1</a> 

<ul class="sub-menu">
<li><a href="/subitem-1/">Subitem 1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="/subitem-2/">Subitem 2</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><a href="/menu-item-2/">Menu Item 2</a></li>

</ul> ​

ul.ipro_menu a.active-parent  {
color: #FF0000;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the direct children selector:

```
ul.ipro_menu li.active-parent > a {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

this will only affect direct descendants of your li element.